# How to change an image's ImageUrl attribute on page load with asp.net and C# in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, image

I have links on a homepage that may or may not have attachments associated with them.  If the links have attachments, then an icon will be placed next to the link.  The icon will only be there if the link has an attachment.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Image pic in imgAttachment)
            {
                 int type = ds.Current_Events[index].AttachmentID;
                 //ds is the dataset
```

The foreach loop is going through each of the "Current Event" pictures on the homepage then getting the type of attachment associated with each link aka the AtachmentID.  The AttachmentID can be a 0, 1, 2, or 3 which means no attachment, photo attached, video attached, or document attached repectively.

A switch statement is then used to change the ImageUrl attribute to the corresponding picture.

```
                 switch (type)
                     {
                            case 0:
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                pic.ImageUrl = "images/eventicons/Photo.jpg";
                                //changed from just "Photo.jpg"
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                pic.ImageUrl = "images/eventicons/Video.jpg";
                                //changed from just "Video.jpg"
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                pic.ImageUrl = "images/eventicons/Doc.jpg";
                                //changed from just "Doc.jpg"
                                break;
                            default:
                                pic.Visible = false;
                                break;
                      }
                  index++;
            }
    }
```

The image does not load in IE, however it does work for firefox.

The following is the aspx front

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="lblEvent1" runat="server">              
           <img src="images/bar_blank.gif" />
      </asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="lblEvent2" runat="server">
           <img src="images/bar_blank.gif" />
      </asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The pictures that I was using were almost 500kb.  I assumed the disk space size of the pictures were small because the images themselves were small but this was not true.  I resized the images and got them down to around 40kb.  The images now load in ie.

So, there seems to be a problem in ie if you change the ImageUrl of an image control in asp.net during page load and the image file you are pointing to is large (500kb).

The solution is to make the picture itself take up less disk space by resizing it, making it a gif, ect..

Answer (score 1):

You should add the full path to your images.  Instead of

```
pic.ImageUrl = "Photo.jpg";
```

you could do this to have ASP.Net write out the path of the photo as well...

```
pic.ImageUrl = "~/MyImagePath/Photo.jpg";
```

Comment: I've made the change but that did not load the image in ie

Comment: I see you updated the code in your question - are you using the tilde?  That will tell asp.net to write out the full path to the image as it renders, rather than trying to use the relative.

Comment: We've run into instances where it was necessary to do this:
pic.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/MyImagePath/Photo.jpg")

I think we were adding the image control to the page from the code-behind.

Comment: @Scott Ivey believe it or not when I add the tilde the image no longer loads in firefox in addition to ie.  

@Jeremy Bade Unfortuantly that still didn't load the image in ie, but it did work in firefox (it worked without it as well).

Answer (score 0):

What does the html code look like that is being produced from your code? Could you post this as there are know issues with the way IE and firefox renders images based on how you reference your image. Would be good to see the rendering as well as your code behind.